# How to find the widest and narrowest part of an object?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I am new to the world of image processing. And I am working on a project, where I need to find the narrowest and widest part of a letter/object like the one I have attached to the post. I have tried many things, but I do not get proper results. Can you help with a way to approach this. I am mostly using Python and OpenCV.
Thanks in advance! [image: Image of an H]

Comment: Do you really mean to measure the width of the left upright of the `h` like that? Normally you measure **perpendicularly** to the edges. If you rotate your image 70 degrees clockwise, that width becomes very large...

Comment: fully automatic? or can you ask the user to click a few points on the image?

Comment: @MarkSetchell. Thank you for the question. Yes you are right, it should be measured perpendicularly to the edges, sorry for my bad drawings.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thank you for the question. It needs to be fully automatic, because I need to measure it for more than 130.000 different font styles and on the following single letter representations: "H", "p", "k", "x", "o", "a".